# Wann benutzt man Definite Pronomen wann Personalpronomen in den Situationen?

Tags: meaning, pronoun

Kann ich für die Sachen "Personalpronomen" verwenden? Zum Beispiel:

> Sie riecht nicht mehr gut/sie ist abgelaufen. (Vorher wurde Die Milch erwähnt)?

Soweit ich verstanden habe, werden Personalpronomen für Personen verwendet, die/der/das für Sachen. Aber oft höre und lese ich auch "er, sie, es" für Sachen.

Wie unterscheiden sie sich?

Answer (score 3):

Personalpronomen heißen so, weil sie in der ersten, zweiten oder dritten *Person* stehen können. Sie werden aber  (in der dritten Person) sowohl für Personen als auch für Sachen benutzt, da gibt es keinen Unterschied.

> Er schüttete die Milch weg, denn sie war sauer.

Im mündlichen Gebrauch wird stattdessen oft der/die/das (als Demonstrativpronomen) benutzt, aber das gilt auch sowohl für Personen als auch  für Sachen.

> "Kannst du die Milch bitte wegschütten? Die ist sauer."
> "Hast du Otto gesehen? Der trägt jetzt einen Vollbart."

Answer (score 1):

> kann ich für die Sachen "Personalpronomen" verwenden.

Ja, definitiv. Zum Unterschied von etwa der englischen Sprache hat das Deutsche grammatikalische Geschlechter, die auch in den Personalpronomina durchgehalten werden:

> der + Maskulinum - *er*
> die + Femininum - *sie*
> das + Neutrum - *es*

Im Vergleich dazu werden auf Englisch lediglich Menschen (nach ihrem natürlichen Geschlecht) und andere, nichtmenschliche - durchaus aber auch belebte - Dinge unterschieden, mit der selten angewandten Ausnahme, daß Dinge von großem affektivem Wert (hauptsächlich Schiffe) weibliche Personalpronomina verwenden:

> The ship arrived. *She* came early.

Hingegen, der Normalfall:

> The man arrived. *He* came early.
> The woman arrived. *She* came early.
> The parcel arrived. *It* came early.
> The dog arrived. *It* came early.

Im Deutschen dagegen entsprechend dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht:

> Der Teig ist fertig. *Er* wird jetzt gebacken.
> Die Milch muß weg. *Sie* ist sauer.
> Das Essen ist fertig. *Es* wird serviert.

Entsprechendes gilt übrigens auch für Possessivpronomina. Maskulina verlangen "sein", Feminina "ihr" und Neutra "sein".