# Wann kann man Demonstrativpronomen anstatt Personalpronomen benutzen?

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun

Gibt es eine definitive Regel, die sagt, wann man Demonstrativpronomen anstatt Personalpronomen benutzen kann?

Zum Beispiel

> Wo ist dann deine Schwester?  Ich habe **sie** seit langem nicht gesehen.

> Wo ist dann deine Schwester?  Ich habe **die** seit langem nicht gesehen.

Ich habe [diese Seite in Lingolia](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/pronouns/demonstrative-pronouns) angeschaut, und zwar gibt es ein Beispiel davon

> Wer ist der Junge? – Das weiß ich nicht. Den kenne ich nicht.

aber ich sehe nicht, dass es die Sache wirklich erklärt.  (Übrigens, ürsprunglich hatte ich an Demonstrativpronomen wie "der/die/das" gedacht.  Trotzdem spricht Lingolia über andere Demonstrativpronomen, wie "dieser" und "derselbe", also würde ich auch gern wissen, wie man am besten mit diesen {könnte man hier "denen" sagen?} umgehen sollte.)

Ich habe [dieses Stack-Exchange-Posting](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73098/wann-benutzt-man-definite-pronomen-wann-personalpronomen-in-den-situationen) gesehen, das folgendes sagt

> *Er schüttete die Milch weg, denn sie war sauer.*
>
> Im mündlichen Gebrauch wird stattdessen oft der/die/das (als
> Demonstrativpronomen) benutzt, aber das gilt auch sowohl für Personen
> als auch für Sachen.
>
> *"Kannst du die Milch bitte wegschütten? Die ist sauer."*
>
> *"Hast du Otto gesehen? Der trägt jetzt einen Vollbart."*

aber ich glaube, dass ich diese Benutzung der Demonstrativpronomen oftmals außer dem mündlichen Gebrauch gesehen habe.

Mein Deutschlehrer hat mehrmals meine Benutzung von Demonstrativpronomen korrigiert -- ich neigte dazu, sie zu oft zu benutzen -- ohne wirklich zu erklären, wann man sie benutzen darf und wann nicht.

Comment: Und auch wenn es zwei Personalpronomen geben würden?  Z.B, in Hinsicht auf einige Blumen, "Sie hat die schon gekauft" anstatt "Sie hat sie schon gekauft"?

Comment: Dazu: In deinem Beispiel, gehe ich davon aus, dass das ein mündlicher Ausdruck ist.  Würdest du es auch so schreiben?

Answer (score 1):

Nein, es gibt keine *definitive* Regel, und die Germanistik ist sich auch nicht zu 100% sicher. Wahrscheinlich ist es auch für jeden Sprecher anders, aber die grobe Tendenz ist klar. Diese Antwort bezieht sich auf gesprochenes Deutsch, formelles, geschriebenes Deutsch hat andere Regeln.

##### Unterschied der Pronomen

Das Problem an deinen Beispielen ist, dass Demonstrativpronomen und Personalpronomen hier genau das gleiche Ding bezeichnen. Der Unterschied wird erst dann klar, wenn es zwei Dinge gibt, die bezeichnet werden können, und da stehen "der" und "er" meist für unterschiedliche. Beispiel:

> Meine Schwester hat gestern Anneliese getroffen. *Sie* hat sich sehr gefreut. 
> Meine Schwester hat gestern Anneliese getroffen. *Die* hat sich sehr gefreut.

Beim ersten Satz ist eher die Schwester, beim zweiten auf jeden Fall Anneliese gemeint. Die Regeln, wann etwas mit "sie" bzw. "die" bezeichnet wird, ist ungefähr so:

1. Personalpronomen stehen in aufeinanderfolgenden Sätzen immer für das gleiche.

> Sie hat Anneliese getroffen. Sie hat sich sehr gefreut.

2. Generell steht das Personalpronomen eher für das Topik / das Subjekt / denjenigen, aus dessen Sicht etwas passiert. Und das Demonstrativpronomen steht dann nicht für das Ding.

   Ob es Subjekt, Topik, oder das, aus dessen Sicht etwas passiert ist, ist (auch der Forschung) nicht ganz klar und meist nicht so wichtig, da das fast immer gleich ist. Das erklärt aber das Beispiel: "Meine Schwester" ist wegen "mein" wahrscheinlich eher bekannter bzw. weniger überraschend als Anneliese, deshalb ist sie das Topik und wir können vielleicht auch annehmen, das es aus der Perspektive von der Schwester erzählt ist. Also steht "sie" hier wohl für die Schwester, und "die" eher nicht.

##### Was verwenden?

Was ist jetzt also im Fall, dass beides eh für das gleiche steht? Da verraten uns die Regeln die Tendenzen. Regel 1 sorgt dafür, dass wir gerne Personalpronomen benutzen, wenn wir lange über das gleiche Ding reden. Ich glaube sogar, dass man von "die" zu "sie" wechselt, sobald man lange genug über etwas redet. Andersherum wechseln wir normalerweise nie von "sie" zu "die". Wegen Regel 2 bezeichnet man etwas eher mit "sie", wenn es das Thema ist. In

> Hast du Otto gesehen? Der trägt jetzt einen Vollbart.

ist z.B. Otto auf keinen Fall das Thema / die Perspektive des ersten Satzes, sondern "du". Damit ist "der" einfach natürlicher und eindeutiger, vor allem wegen so ähnlichen Sätzen wie

> Hat *er* Otto gesehen? Er/Der sah so erschrocken aus.

(Ich habe den Vollbart-Satz ersetzt, da der Satz sonst nicht so viel Sinn macht.)

##### Einwände von Sprachästhetikern

Auch wenn es völlig sinnvoll und logisch ist, "der" und "er" bzw. "die" und "sie" so für Menschen zu verwenden, so gibt es immer noch die, die es nicht mögen, "die" und "der" für Menschen verwendet zu sehen. Für die ist das Umgangssprache oder schlechter Stil – auf Menschen zeigt man nicht – und sie vermeiden aktiv, Menschen mit Demonstrativpronomen zu bezeichnen.

##### In geschriebenen Deutsch

Abgesehen von "das", was für den gesamten letzten Satz steht, werden Demonstrativpronomen in geschriebenen Deutsch fast nie verwendet. Ich habe z.B. gerade 3 Artikel gelesen, wo kein einziges außer dieses "das" auftaucht. Stattdessen werden fast ausschließlich Personalpronomen verwendet, oder halt "diese", aber in deutlich geringerem Unfang. Die einzige Ausnahme ist vielleicht noch "dessen" / "deren", weil man das mit "dieses" nicht ersetzen kann.

> Thomas fragte seinen Sohn, ob er *dessen* Auto leihen dürfte.

Auch bei Relativsätzen, wo man gesprochen oder wenig formell

> Neue Anlagen brauchen länger als die, die vor drei Jahren installiert wurden.

steht geschrieben häufig

> Neue Anlagen brauchen länger als *diejenigen*, die vor drei Jahren installiert wurden.

Answer (score -5):

Bei synchronischer Betrachtung ist der entscheidende Unterschied im Vocatif zwischen der formellen Höflichkeitsform *Sie* und der der informellen Unhöflichkeitsform *du* bzw. *Du* zu verorten. Die Herkunft ist dem Muttersprachler nicht geläufig und spielt insofern keine Rolle.

Die Herkunft der Demonstrativ- und Personalpronomen ist davon zu unterscheiden, wird in der Praxis jedoch nicht beachtet, zumal das Demonstrativpronomen eine untergegangene Form ähnlich *sie* hatte.

In dieser Hinsicht ist es bei diachroner Betrachtungsweise durchaus nicht falsch, *sie* wie ein Demonstrativpronomen gleich dem Artikel *die* zu benutzen.

Es mag durchaus der Fall sein, dass dies einem bisher unterbeleuchtetem Lautwandel zuzuschreiben ist. Insoweit ist eine theoretisch fundierte Antwort kaum zu erwarten.